# Concurrent development on Siebel : Are there any tools available to automatically sync Siebel SRF

Tags: config, siebel

We have teams working on 2 parallel releases on Siebel 7.7 based application. Both these releases may require SRF changes. Currently, the teams manually re-key the SRF changes from one release to another. Are there any tools that can automatically compare SRF data, highlight conflicts and sync them.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried exporting.importing SIF files?
Goto Projects, search for ones that have changed recently, Export to Archive, and then Import into your other repository. Diffs etc will be automatically shown.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Siebel 8, tools itself has a compare SRF option. Tools > Utilities > Compare SRFs. However, there is no option of syncing changes. For that, you will have use SIFs from the repositories.

Its a good idea to use third party CVS tools like MS SourceSafe for version management.